# Remove grouped data set when total of count is zero with subquery

Tags: sql

I'm generating a data set that looks like this

```
category    user     total

   1      jonesa       0

   2      jonesa       0

   3      jonesa       0

   1      smithb       0

   2      smithb       0

   3      smithb       5

   1      brownc       2

   2      brownc       3

   3      brownc       4
```

Where a particular user has 0 records in **all** categories is it possible to remove their rows form the set? If a user has some activity like smithb does, I'd like to keep all of their records. Even the zeroes rows. Not sure how to go about that, I thought a CASE statement may be of some help but I'm not sure, this is pretty complicated for me. Here is my query

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.category,
  u.user_name,
  CASE WHEN (
    SELECT COUNT(e.entry_id)
    FROM category c1 
    INNER JOIN entry e1
      ON c1.category_id = e1.category_id
      WHERE c1.category_id = c.category_id
      AND e.user_name = u.user_name
      AND e1.entered_date >= TO_DATE ('20140625','YYYYMMDD')
      AND e1.entered_date <= TO_DATE ('20140731', 'YYYYMMDD')) > 0 -- I know this won't work
    THEN 'Yes'
  ELSE NULL
  END AS TOTAL
FROM user u 
INNER JOIN role r
  ON u.id = r.user_id
    AND r.id IN (1,2),
    category c 
LEFT JOIN entry e
  ON c.category_id = e.category_id
WHERE c.category_id NOT IN (19,20)
```

I realise the case statement won't work, but it was an attempt on how this might be possible. I'm really not sure if it's possible or the best direction. Appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this, but the less verbose the SQL is, the harder it may be for you to follow along with the logic.  For that reason, I think that using multiple Common Table Expressions will avoid the need to use redundant joins, while being the most readable.

```
-- assuming user_name and category_name are unique on [user] and [category] respectively.  

WITH valid_categories (category_id, category_name) AS 
(
    -- get set of valid categories
    SELECT c.category_id, c.category AS category_name
    FROM category c
    WHERE c.category_id NOT IN (19,20)
),
valid_users ([user_name]) AS 
(
    -- get set of users who belong to valid roles
    SELECT u.[user_name]
    FROM [user] u 
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM [role] r
        WHERE u.id = r.[user_id] AND r.id IN (1,2)
    )

),
valid_entries (entry_id, [user_name], category_id, entry_count) AS
(
    -- provides a flag of 1 for easier aggregation
    SELECT e.[entry_id], e.[user_name], e.category_id, CAST( 1 AS INT) AS entry_count
    FROM [entry] e  
    WHERE e.entered_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('20140625','YYYYMMDD') AND TO_DATE('20140731', 'YYYYMMDD')
    -- determines if entry is within date range 
),
user_categories ([user_name], category_id, category_name) AS

(   SELECT u.[user_name], c.category_id, c.category_name
    FROM valid_users u
    -- get the cartesian product of users and categories
    CROSS JOIN valid_categories c
    -- get only users with a valid entry 
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM valid_entries e
        WHERE e.[user_name] = u.[user_name]
    )
)

/*

You can use these for testing.

SELECT COUNT(*) AS valid_categories_count
FROM valid_categories

SELECT COUNT(*) AS valid_users_count
FROM valid_users

SELECT COUNT(*) AS valid_entries_count
FROM valid_entries

SELECT COUNT(*) AS users_with_entries_count
FROM valid_users u
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM user_categories uc
    WHERE uc.user_name = u.user_name
)

SELECT COUNT(*) AS users_without_entries_count
FROM valid_users u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM user_categories uc
    WHERE uc.user_name = u.user_name
)

SELECT uc.[user_name], uc.[category_name], e.[entry_count] 
FROM user_categories uc
INNER JOIN  valid_entries e ON (uc.[user_name] = e.[user_name] AND uc.[category_id] = e.[category_id])
*/

-- Finally, the results: 

SELECT uc.[user_name], uc.[category_name], SUM(NVL(e.[entry_count],0)) AS [entry_count]
FROM user_categories uc
LEFT OUTER JOIN  valid_entries e ON (uc.[user_name] = e.[user_name] AND uc.[category_id] = e.[category_id])
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me, I have been through everything, but the final statement I get an error in TOAD, `ISNULL is invalid identifier`, should this be `IS NULL`? Because that errors too, it says missing expression.

Comment: You'll also want to correct the where clause of the "valid_entries" CTE.

Comment: Thanks! You are an SQL sorcerer!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
delete from t1
where user in (
  select user
  from t1
  group by user
  having count(distinct category) = sum(case when total=0 then 1 else 0 end) )
```

The sub query can get all the users fit your removal requirement.

`count(distinct category)` get how many category a user have.
`sum(case when total=0 then 1 else 0 end)` get how many rows with activities a user have.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another method:

```
WITH totals AS (
  SELECT
    c.category,
    u.user_name,
    COUNT(e.entry_id) AS total,
    SUM(COUNT(e.entry_id)) OVER (PARTITION BY u.user_name) AS user_total
  FROM
    user u
  INNER JOIN
    role r ON u.id = r.user_id
  CROSS JOIN
    category c
  LEFT JOIN
    entry e ON c.category_id = e.category_id
           AND u.user_name = e.user_name
           AND e1.entered_date >= TO_DATE ('20140625', 'YYYYMMDD')
           AND e1.entered_date <= TO_DATE ('20140731', 'YYYYMMDD')
  WHERE
    r.id IN (1, 2)
    AND c.category_id IN (19, 20)
  GROUP BY
    c.category,
    u.user_name
)
SELECT
  category,
  user_name,
  total
FROM
  totals
WHERE
  user_total > 0
;
```

The `totals` derived table calculates the totals per user and category as well as totals across all categories per user (using `SUM() OVER ...`). The main query returns only rows where the user total is greater than zero.